# Why can't I disable shortcut / desktop icon delete without disabling important maintenance?

Tags: windows, windows-10, automatic-maintenance

I don't want Windows 10 to remove shortcuts from my task bar or icons from my desktop for any reason. And yet apparently the only way to disable this behavior, is to [also disable the entire Scheduled Maintenance task](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/prevent-broken-shortcuts-being-removed-in-windows/2d7e4600-742b-4aab-87c7-ca9935caf202), which includes time synchronization and disk error checks.

And even when you disable it, it keeps getting re-enabled after certain system updates, which I imagine is by design since you really do want the other parts running.

Is there no other way to control the Scheduled Maintenance process? Because that doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'm afraid this is all-or-nothing.

Comment: Not a solution, but an awkward workaround: make a Zip file with all shortcuts, and keep a copy. If Windows Maintenance or Update gets rid of what it determines as "invalid shortcuts", open the Zip archive and redeploy them.